# Configure PHP bundled with MAC OS

Tags: php, macos, apache

I want to run my php applications using php bundled with MAC os. I have done some changes and after that i have started my apache server using

```
sudo apachectl
```

restart and running localhost now shows pages available at

```
/Library/WebServer/Documents/index.html.en
```

where should i keep my custom php application so that it can be viewable by browser on localhost.

Comment: If pages that you save in `/Library/WebServer/Documents` show up in `http://localhost/`... wouldn't it be a logical step to put your custom PHP application in `/Library/WebServer/Documents`? I'd also suggest trying out [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/en/) for your local stack

Comment: There used to be a feature in previous versions of Mac OS X where you could have user sites: You'd store your files in the Sites directory of your home directory and would be able to access them via `http://localhost/~username`. This can be reenabled but I'd need to look into it

Comment: @sjagr : you are right but i don`t want to put it there but at some place easliy accessible.

Comment: @AdamElsodaney, you are right and i even tried with that but of no use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a Symlink to have a more easily accessible path:

```
ln -s /Users/NewBee/Desktop/mycustomappinanaccessibleplace /Library/WebServer/Documents/my_app
```

You may run into permissions problems, make sure you account for that by ensuring the apache user can access the files and symlink.

Your other option is to change the `DocumentRoot` in your `httpd.conf` file.